# How to only hide the anchor which has not text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a slider made up of multiple images and on each image there is an anchor element (treated as a button).

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The placement of the anchor without text isn't always determined as users can add more slides as they wish.

Currently everything is displaying as it should, however if there is no text insrted in the anchor tag, the whole anchor is displayed.

How can I hide just the anchors which have no text?

I have tried something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     if (jQuery('.slider-btn').text() !== 0){
         jQuery('.slider-btn').show();
     }else{
         jQuery('.slider-btn').hide();
     }
 });
```

However this statement will return all the texts in all the buttons, forcing it to show.

Any help to put me on the right path will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire div? The button without text is not visible to begin with.

Comment: First of you missing closing some of your classes `<a class="slider-btn>` is missing the `"` at the end, second you could maybe just use `jQuery('.slider-btn:empty').hide()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the heads up on the missing quotes. WOW I tried using the :empty and it worked exactly how I wanted. If you post this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: Also, you can do that with CSS: `a.slider-btn:empty { display: none; }`

Comment: `.text()` will *never* `!== 0` it might `!= 0` but when you use `!==` it uses type matching and `.text()` is text while `0` is an integer.  Your code would have worked if you did `jQuery('.slider-btn').text() !== ""` (and looped each anchor)

Comment: @Qirel I want to hide the anchor tag only. I used the answer from Carsten and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Well.. The anchor doesn't display anything if it doesn't have any text within it, so I fail to see the point here..? Am I missing something? `<a ..></a>` is not visible anywhere.

Comment: @Qirel I thought that at first, but it will show if there's some css applied eg `a { border: 1px solid red; }` will show as a single red line.

Comment: Then you can simply do it wish CSS, as @ThomasAltmann wrote. No need for JS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the button using CSS only:

```
.slider-btn:empty {
 display: none;
}
```

[CSS empty selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

This is similar to `jQuery('.slider-btn:empty').hide()` but it doesn't use JS and won't add the inline-style `display:none`. Both approaches will work, though.

Comment: Thanks! This is the cleanest way to do it. +1 for the tip on not using JS

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through jQuery and CSS - using CSS is easiest and better, so I recommend that.

The approach is the same, using the `:empty` selector.

#### Using CSS (recommended)

```css
.slider-btn:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Using jQuery

Find all the anchors where button is empty, and use `hide()` on that!

```js
$(".slider").find('.slider-btn:empty').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop trough the a elements with an each function. Check if it contains an empty string as text. If so hide the parent.

```js
$('.slider-btn').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() === "") {
    $(this).parent('.slide').hide();
    //or this if you only want to hide the button, but then you better off with css
    //$(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn">SOME TEXT HERE 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    //img and extra html

    <a class="slider-btn"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is to only hide the button when it's empty, not the slide that contains it

Comment: Edited my answer, but Your answer doing it with css is more efficient in that case.